# iterating through vector array error bs lc first question

Tags: algorithm, c++11, binary-search

```
class Solution {
   
public:

   

int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {

     int count=0;

    for(unsigned long i=0; i<nums.size(); ++i){
        if(nums[i]==target)
        { return nums[i]; ++count; break;}
    }

        

    
    if(count==0) return -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please ask a question. If there is an error, then show us what the error is.

Comment: After including necessary headers, this code [compiles without errors](https://godbolt.org/z/W74fxdE7j) for me. It may not make much sense, but it does compile.